# Positivity of coefficients of the inverse of a certain power series

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series, operads, inverse-series

Consider the unique formal power series $g(z)$ with $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=1$ satisfying the equation 
 $$
g(z)-g(z)^8+g(z)^{15}=z,
 $$
that is the inverse of
 $$
z-z^8+z^{15} 
 $$
in the group of formal power series of the form $z+O(z^2)$. Does this series have any non-positive coefficients of powers $z^{7k+1}$? (Other coefficients are manifestly zero).

**Background.**  Existence of non-positive coefficients among those would imply that a certain operad fails the Ginzburg-Kapranov test for Koszulness. (See http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.1505).

**Comments.**  The first ten thousand or so of those coefficients are positive. Some elementary complex analysis approaches didn't work, but maybe I am not aware of some useful tricks.

Comment: To save others a small amount of calculation, what Lagrange's Inversion formula gives you is that the coefficient of $z^{7k+1}$ in $g(z)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{7k+1}$ times the coefficient of $t^k$ in $(1-t+t^2)^{-7k-1}$. (I don't know how to use that information to show the coefficient is positive.)

Comment: Write it as a contour integral, use the saddle point method, conclude that since the saddle point is on the positive semi-axis, all sufficiently large coefficients are positive, check that 10,000 is a large enough number (honestly, I wouldn't really bother about the last step), and declare this attempt a failure.

Comment: Here is a conjectured generalization. Let $\Phi_n(x)$ be the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial. Without loss of generality we may assume that $n$ is squarefree. Let $f_n(k)$ be the coefficient of $x^k$ in $\Phi_n(x)^{−(n+1)k−1}$. If $n$ has an even number of distinct prime divisors, then $f_n(k)>0$. Otherwise $(−1)^kf_n(k)>0$.

Comment: I wonder if the strengthening $\sum_{s\geq 0}\binom{7k+s}{s}_q\binom{7k+1}{k-3s}_q (-1)^s\in \mathbb N[q]$ is true?

Comment: @fedja thanks! In fact, this is good news that in this case the GK test doesn't give an answer.

Comment: @RichardStanley Why not post your conjectured generalization as a new MO question? it looks interesting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Combining Omar and fedja's comments gives a quick solution. By the [Lagrange Inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), we want to show that the coefficient of $t^k$ in $(1-t+t^2)^{-(7k+1)}$ is positive. Writing this as a contour integral, we want to compute
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint \frac{dt}{t (1-t+t^2)} \left( \frac{1}{t (1-t+t^2)^7} \right)^k.$$

Set $f(t) = \tfrac{1}{t(1-t+t^2)}$ and $g(t) = \frac{1}{t(1-t+t^2)^7}$, so we want $\tfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint f(t) g(t)^k dt$.
The critical points of $g$ are at $t=1/5$ and $t=1/3$, so take our contour to be a circle of radius $1/5$ around the origin. We want $\tfrac{1}{10 \pi} \int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi} f(e^{i \theta}/5) e^{i \theta} g(e^{i \theta}/5)^k d \theta$.

We have $g(1/5) = \tfrac{30517578125}{1801088541} \approx 17$, and $g(e^{i \theta}/5)$ smaller than that for all other $\theta$. We set $a=g(1/5)$. Here is a plot of $|g(e^{i \theta}/5)|$; I leave rigorous proof for others. So values of $\theta$ very near $0$ dominate the integral. The Taylor series for $g(e^{i \theta}/5)$ starts $a-b \theta^2$ where $b=\tfrac{152587890625}{37822859361}>0$. (Note the absence of an $i \theta$ term, because we chose a path through the critical point.)

[image]

Also, $f(1/5)=\tfrac{121}{25}>0$, call this $c$. So the integral is roughly $\int c (a-b \theta^2)^k d \theta \approx \int c a^k e^{-(b/a)k \theta^2} d \theta = \frac{C}{\sqrt{k}} a^k$ for some positive $C$. In particular, it is positive for large enough $k$ and, as fedja says, $10000$ is going to be way more than enough. I leave rigorous bounds to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very pleased both with the proof and the result proved.